# EF 4.1 RC - 'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer`1[TContext]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TContext'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I've just updated my project (using NuGet) to Entity Framework 4.1 RC and receives this error msg:

> GenericArguments[0],
>   'Notesnhac.Library.NotesnhacContext',
>   on
>   'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer`1[TContext]'
>   violates the constraint of type
>   parameter 'TContext'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception
>   occurred during the execution of the
>   current web request. Please review the
>   stack trace for more information about
>   the error and where it originated in
>   the code.
>
> Exception Details:
>   System.TypeLoadException:
>   GenericArguments[0],
>   'Notesnhac.Library.NotesnhacContext',
>   on
>   'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer`1[TContext]'
>   violates the constraint of type
>   parameter 'TContext'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line
>   114:          DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new
>   StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
>   Line 115:         #endregion Line 116:        }
>   Line 117: } Line 118:}
>
> Source File: C:\projects\Kenny
>   Projects\Notesnhac\Notesnhac.Site\Global.asax.cs
>   Line: 116
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [TypeLoadException:
>   GenericArguments[0],
>   'Notesnhac.Library.NotesnhacContext',
>   on
>   'System.Data.Entity.IDatabaseInitializer`1[TContext]'
>   violates the constraint of type
>   parameter 'TContext'.]
>   Notesnhac.Site.MvcApplication.Application_Start()
>   in C:\projects\Kenny
>   Projects\Notesnhac\Notesnhac.Site\Global.asax.cs:116
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET
>   Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET
>   Version:4.0.30319.225

It says the error is on line 116 but I don't think it's where the error is. Here's a snip of the code where it says the error, line #116 is the curly brace right after `#endregion`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    // Initalizes the database
    System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<NotesnhacContext>(new ContextInitializer());

    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    AutoMapperConfig.CreateMappings();

    ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Notesnhac.Site.Controllers");

    #region StructureMap IoC
    IContainer container = new Container(x =>
    {
        x.For<IControllerActivator>().Use<StructureMapControllerActivator>();
        x.Scan(s =>
        {
            s.Assembly("Notesnhac.Library");
            s.TheCallingAssembly();
            s.AddAllTypesOf<IController>().NameBy(type => type.Name.Replace("Controller", "").ToLower());
            s.WithDefaultConventions();
        });
    });
    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new StructureMapDependencyResolver(container));
    #endregion
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the line:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer<NotesnhacContext>(new ContextInitializer());
```

The generic parameter `TContext` is [required to be a DbContext subtype](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679461%28v=VS.103%29.aspx). And your strategy must implement IDatabaseInitializer.

You don't show the declaration of `NotesnhacContext`, but the compiler says that one of these is missing.

You shouldn't need to specify the type parameter at all; it will be inferred from the argument. You can just do:

```
System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new ContextInitializer());
```

...presuming you first fix the issue with the declaration.

Comment: Ah, there were some changes to the API in this release that I didn't aware of :) Thanks for pointing that out Craig.